# how Object function for each

Tags: javascript

no result data, how can I get data from one of the objects in the names array by supplying the name? and class info for list query and show.

```js
$.when(Data('')).then(function(result) {
  var results = result.d.results;
  var html = "";

  html = "<table>";

  $.each(results, function(key, fila) {
    console.log("Data ", fila); //no result 
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + lack name + "</td><td>" + lack occupation + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
  });

  html += "</table>";

  $(".info").html(html);

});

function Data() {
//how to get object name
  var person = {
    name: "Tahir Akhtar",
    occupation: "Software Development"
  };
  var p1 = "name";
  var p2 = "occupation";
  alert(person[p1]);
  alert(person[p2]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `$.when()`? `Data()` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: In fact, `Data()` doesn't return anything, there's no way for the caller to access anything from the `person` object.

Comment: You should phrase your question more clearly. Pretend for a moment that you are someone else reading this question, having no idea who the OP is and what they are trying to do. Would you understand what the question is? It also wouldn't hurt to add a bit of context. Give this help center page on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a quick read. Also, refrain from just dumping all your code into the question. Instead, try your best to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Barmar I understand you can give an example

Comment: I think you are trying to access the values in the object. So you can access like this `person.name` which will return name value in the object. If you have array of objects you can use `Object.map` for iterating through the object and get the values.

Comment: @DiegoSagredo Add `return person` to the function. Then you can use `result.name` and `result.occupation` to access the properties.

Comment: @Barmar, yes result but not each and for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the object from the function. The object it returns will then be the `result` in the `.then()` callback function. You can then loop through the properties with `$.each()`.

```js
$.when(Data()).then(function(result) {
  var html = "";

  html = "<table>";
  var headerRow = "";
  var dataRow = "";
  $.each(result, function(key, fila) {
    console.log("Data ", fila); //no result 
    headerRow += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
    dataRow += "<td>" + fila + "</td>";
  });
  
  html += "<tr>" + headerRow + "</tr>";
  html += "<tr>" +  dataRow + "</tr>";
  html += "</table>";

  $(".info").html(html);

});

function Data() {
//how to get object name
  var person = {
    name: "Tahir Akhtar",
    occupation: "Software Development"
  };
  var p1 = "name";
  var p2 = "occupation";
  alert(person[p1]);
  alert(person[p2]);
  return person;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Comment: Barmar, thank you. but i add  var person = [
       {name:"John", occupation: "Software Development"},
       {name:"Peter", occupation: "Information"}
  ];

Comment: That's a different question.